# Can't change permissions on file system (SD card) Solved

Tags: filesystems, mount, file-permissions, read-only

I have a SanDisk SD card (64 G). I had it loaded with berryboot and Kali Linux. I made the mistake of mounting the boot partition in fstab and when rebooted it gets stuck in a loop with berryboot’s config setup. I have tried to `wipefs`, `dd if=/zero`, and `gparted` to wipe the thing back to square one. Nothing worked because it’s a read-only file system. I have tried `chmod` and `/dev/sdb mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb` and nothing. I can't seem to find a solution with my tools to get this back to being useable. Can somebody point me in the right direction or have any knowledge of any tools to get this writable? I have tried all of this as root. Here are some errors I have encountered:

from the command line:

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sdb
mount: /dev/sdb: mount point not mounted or bad option.
 ✘ ⚙ arcarius@archlinux  ~  sudo chown arcarius:root /dev/sdb
 ⚙ arcarius@archlinux  ~  ls -l /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 arcarius root 8, 16 Nov 14 19:52 /dev/sdb
 ⚙ arcarius@archlinux  ~  sudo chmod u+w /dev/sdb
 ⚙ arcarius@archlinux  ~  ls -l /dev/sdb         
brw-rw---- 1 arcarius root 8, 16 Nov 14 19:52 /dev/sdb
 ⚙ arcarius@archlinux  ~  Error while mounting /dev/sdb on /me: Read-only file system
```

```
✘ ⚙ arcarius@archlinux  ~  sudo wipefs /dev/sdb 
[sudo] password for root: 
DEVICE OFFSET TYPE UUID LABEL
sdb    0x1fe  dos       
 ⚙ arcarius@archlinux  ~  sudo wipefs --all --force /dev/sdb
wipefs: error: /dev/sdb: probing initialization failed: Read-only file system
 ✘ ⚙ arcarius@archlinux  ~  sudo wipefs --all --force /dev/sdb1
wipefs: /dev/sdb1: failed to erase vfat magic string at offset 0x00000036: Operation not permitted
 ✘ ⚙ arcarius@archlinux  ~  sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb && sync status=progress                          
dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb': Read-only file system
 ✘ ⚙ arcarius@archlinux  ~  sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/sdb && sync status=progress
dd: failed to open '/dev/sdb': Read-only file system
```

```
 ✘ ⚙ arcarius@archlinux  ~  sudo wipe -r /dev/sdb  
wipe: cannot open `/dev/sdb':Read-only file system
```

```
mount: 
/dev/sdb2 on /run/media/arcarius/berryboot type ext4 (ro,nosuid,nodev,relatime,data=ordered,uhelper=udisks2)
/dev/sdb1 on /mnt type vfat (ro,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
```

Solved, davidgo was right. It was in fact the read-only switch. would have never thought of or had my eye open for such a thing.

Comment: Doing a dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX should bypass any filesystem locks.  I wonder if you have bumped the switch on the side of the SD Card to READ-ONLY?

Comment: Wow, I had no idea there was a button there for that. Thanks. I just hit the switch and I’ll load it up and see. Be right back.